# How to disable PayPal express payment method on one of the store

Tags: magento2.3, payment-methods, paypal-express, enable-disable

I got 2 variations of the store - EU and USA. I need to disable the PayPal Express method on the EU store, how can I do that?

[image]

**There no option to disable Payment on EU store:**
[image]
**But avaliable on default config:**

[image]

Comment: have you tried disabling it via the configuration in the Admin-Backend?

Comment: @PhilippSander watch the screenshots and description that I added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I waste much time to make a bad hack.
Here payments methods displays:

```
<div if="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
 class="items payment-methods">
<div repeat="foreach: paymentGroupsList, item: '$group'"
     class="payment-group">
    <div if="getRegion($group().displayArea)().length"
         translate="getGroupTitle($group)"
         class="step-title"
         data-role="title">
    </div>
    <each args="data: getRegion($group().displayArea), as: 'method'" render=""/>
</div>
```

I changed PayPal title from the admin menu on EU store to `PayPal hidden`

I found the js file that renders this components:

```
Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/payment/list.js
```

Then I check on `initChildren` method this title:

```
        initChildren: function () {
        var self = this;

        _.each(paymentMethods(), function (paymentMethodData) {
            if(paymentMethodData.title!="PayPal hidden") {
                self.createRenderer(paymentMethodData);
            }
        });

        return this;
    },
```